# fetch user facebook information on external website

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

i want to impelment the same technique as stik.com has, if a user is logged into facebook they automatically fetch the user information without any approval, they just relaod the website.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

you can get the user information, `"session user"`  using one of the **sdk**'s, *javascript provided above*.  **NOTE:**  you will still need to request atleast basic permission from the user to get the current users name, id etc;

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/  for guide to integration.